# What is the maximum number of OBD2 PIDs I can reasonably retrieve at the same time?

Tags: obd-ii, can-bus

I have Mazda 5, 2014

recently I've got OBD2 logger which allows to retrieve large amount (several hundred) of PIDs, including standard ones (SAE) and specific PIDs provided by Mazda Enhanced Add-on; all this data goes over bluetooth to my phone and gets stored into csv file.

I want to troubleshoot some intermittent electrical issues and (being unsure what else could be affected) trying to log as many PIDs as my car would safely support; however so far I was unable to find any recommendations, **how many PIDs should I try to retrieve at once**. Would it overload my car's can-bus or obd2 controller if I try to get too many PIDs or retrieve those too often?

Would it make any difference if those PIDs are coming from different subsystems? ("Mazda/Body control module", "Mazda/Powertrain Control Module" etc)

Here is the screenshot with all available PIDs
[image]

[**update**]
Just in case anyone wants to know - here is the problem I was trying to solve by colelcting those PIDs:

Pretty much every time after heavy rain and wind the car might not start or engine would just lose power or stop completely while I am driving; later after day or two the car would just "get dry" and everything gets back to normal until the next rain.

Here are the error codes retrieved after the last such case:

```
 IC (Instrument Cluster)        U0401:68-08     Invalid Data Received From ECM/PCMA

PCM (Powertrain Control Module)  P0340:00-AC    Camshaft Position Sensor A Circuit (Bank 1 Or Single Sensor)

PCM (Powertrain Control Module) P061D:00-AC Internal Control Module Engine Air Mass Performance

TCM (Transmission Control Module) U0401:00-2C Invalid Data Received From ECM/PCMA

ABS (Anti-Lock Brake System) U0401:00-68  Invalid Data Received From ECM/PCMA

EPS (Electronic Power Steering) U2023-FF  Fault Received From External Node
```

Since engine was losing power or just dying after rain, I hoped to get some PIDs indicating, what exactly went wrong right before the engine would die. (there were some frozen frames, but I couldn't see anything wrong there and my mechanic either, so I am trying to collect more data for "normal" driving and "problematic" cases.

Comment: I think the answer is "one". Why, because you send out a request and you get a response. If you stack requests, it's still only responding one at a time, regardless of how many you've stacked. I'm not an expert, though.

Comment: I guess technically you are correct;  in my case "at the same time" meant "pile all those PID requests and keep asking for those PIDs over and over"

Comment: Just like any computer or computer network, you can over do it, that's for sure. Sort of like a DDOS, even though it's not "distributed". My suggestion is, pile it on until something fails.

Comment: If your vehicle doesn't generate error codes to have some idea of whether electrical problems are associated with error codes, PIDs may not help if you aren't familiar with interpreting PIDs that may or may not point to electrical issues. Perhaps describing it here may generate replies related to your descriptions of electrical problems.

Comment: @FDryer There were some DTCs, I have updated the text of the question. Since engine was losing power or just dying after rain, I hoped to get some PIDs  indicating, what exactly went wrong right before the engine would die. (there were some frozen frames, but I couldn't see anything wrong there and my mechanic either, so I am trying to collect more data for "normal" driving and "problematic" cases.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2  I am software developer, so I get the idea of DDos, I just wanted to play it safe since I am not sure what will happen if something there fails while I am driving.

Comment: Since water intrusion from rain creates a temporary short circuit condition killing the engine, attempting to find the cause from error codes may be a matter of separating false errors from one or two actual errors caused by signal or voltage issues. I see several possible false errors, not convinced of the one or two actual errors. Visually examine main power connections, main grounds, fuse panels, and wiring in the engine bay which may give clues. Electrical/electronic gremlins can be either easy or difficult to diagnose and troubleshoot where error codes are usually relied on for help.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't worry. In most cases, your adapter is usually *way* slower than the
CAN connection, so unless your OBD2-adapter has its own logic (which
only a handful do), it's not possible to saturate the CAN bus with
a serial ELM327(-based) adapter. But let's do some computations.

We'll start with the bus ­– lets assume it's 500Kbps (ELM327 protocol 6), with 250Kbps
it's going to take double.

A single OBD2 PID as a CAN frame (with 8 data bytes and standard addressing) has a size of up to 125 bits.
At 500kbps, one single bit needs about 2µs, so it will take 250µs
for the request to be communicated on the bus ­– and another 250µs for the answer.

Now we have no idea how long an ECU takes to answer the request. They're not the fastest
devices out there. For the sake of a simple computation, lets assume that it's a very quick
one that takes only another 500µs to fulfill that request.

So we have 1ms per request/response, which ­– at this point of time ­– translates to a theoretical
maximum of 1000 PIDs per second.

Assuming this is a Bluetooth 3.x adapter (BLE ones are usually even slower, due to the GATT overhead),
it depends on the RFCOMM protocol, typically you will only get
450-500 Kbps.
Unfortunately though, it pretty much depends on the internal UART bitrate
of the ELM327, which often is more like 115200 bps.

Knowing that ELM327 communicates by sending ASCII characters, a request/response
sequence for a typical PID like 010C (Current RPM) looks like that:

```
010C1\r7E804410C5700\r\r>
```

That's 22 characters, so 220 bits for the UART. 220 bits on an UART @ 115200bps
take 1909µs, so almost 2 milliseconds.
(Yes, there is a special ELM327 syntax for combining multiple PID requests, but let's ignore that now)

With 3 milliseconds for a request/response interaction in total, the theoretical maximum would be
333 PIDs per second.

The device that the adapter is connected to though (a computer, a smartphone, a microcontroller) also
needs a bit of time to read the next PID from its list. We don't know how long this takes, but
it's probably neglegible.

While 333 PIDs per second is sounding pretty good, it also depends on whether you are using
broadcast addressing. If you do not know how many ECUs will answer to your request,
the adapter has no chance but to wait. This wait typically introduces an additional 100-250ms per
request, so we quickly come down to 5-10 PIDs per second.

That said, real-life values I've seen vary from 50 to 100 PIDs per second, the latter
only with combinations of good software and high quality hardware adapters.